# How to set up case insensitive routes with Slim framework?

Tags: php, routes, slim

I have the following association between a route and a callback in my application:

```
$api->slim->post('/:accountId/Phone-Numbers/', function($accountId) use ($api) {
    $api->createPhoneNumber($accountId);
});
```

What I want to avoid is having the route `myhost/a7b81cf/phone-numbers/` return a 404 response because Slim understands the route `myhost/a7b81cf/Phone-Numbers/` as being different, due to the usage of uppercase letters.
How can I avoid setting up two separate routes that trigger the same callback function?

Answer (score 6):

This is an old question, but I wanted to provide a clear answer for this problem.

There is a 'routes.case_sensitive' configuration that allows you to do that. I don't know exactly why this is not in the docs (http://docs.slimframework.com/#Application-Settings), but if you look at the framework's source code (specifically, in getDefaultSettings() at Slim.php) you can see that is there.

I just tested it and it works fine.

Summarizing, the solution is to apply the 'routes.case_sensitive' configuration like this:

```
$configurations = [
    // ... other settings ...
    'routes.case_sensitive' => false
];

$app->config($configurations);
```

Comment: Slim 3: `$app = new \Slim\App(['settings' => ['routes.case_sensitive' => false]]);`

Answer (score 0):

You could try with route validation/conditions:

```
$api->slim->post('/:accountId/:phoneNumbers/', function ($accountId) {
    $api->createPhoneNumber($accountId);
})->conditions(array('phoneNumbers' => '(p|P)hone\-(n|N)umbers'));
```

Or if you want more global change you could override Route->matches method in Route class to be case insensitive but it will affect whole application.

Answer (score 0):

You can mimic case-insensitive routing in Slim by registering a hook and modifying the incoming routes to match the case of your defined routes.

In the example, all of your defined routes should be lowercase and `strtolower` is called on all incoming paths:

```
$app->hook('slim.before.router', function () use ($app) {
    $app->environment['PATH_INFO'] = strtolower($app->environment['PATH_INFO']);
});
```